# Php get value of part of url

Tags: php, url

I have a url (as below). I'd like to get the value of "2". How can I get that?

```
http://domain.com/site1/index.php/page/2
```

Comment: you should be using an .htaccess rewrite for this

Comment: @developerwjk Why? You're assuming a lot about where the url value is coming from and why they need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a combination of [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and [`parseurl`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
pathinfo(parseurl($url)['path'])['filename'];
```

`pathinfo` will break the path into well-defined parts, of which `filename` is that last part you're looking for (`2`). If you're looking instaed for the absolute location in the path, you may want to split the path on `/` and simply get the value at index 3.

We can test this like so:

```
<?php
$url = "http://domain.com/site1/index.php/page/2";
$value=pathinfo(parse_url($url)['path'])['filename'];
echo $value."\n";
```

And then on the command line:

```
$ php url.php 
2
```

Comment: @jimmyobonyo Be sure to 'accept' answers that work for you. I notice a lot of your questions don't have an 'accepted' answer; that may hurt you in the future when looking for help.

Comment: sure thats in 5 minute of question answered , also remember to mark up if you think the question/answer is of value fellow SO users

Comment: using `$parts=pathinfo(parseurl($url))['filename'];`
`$path_parts=explode('/', $parts['path']);`
`$paged = $path_parts[count($path_parts)-1];` does not work , why ?

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: `0` is the result am getiing

Comment: Sorry... forgot to include the `path` array index. Updated

Answer (score 0):

I use nathaniel fords example but if you run into a problem where files are named '2.html' some servers will load those even though you have '2'.

You can also do this.

home.php?page=2 as the web address

```
home.php
<?php
    // check to see if $page is set
    $page = $POST[page];
    $page = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $page);
    if(!isset($page)){
       query page two stuff or what you need.
    }
?>
```