# How do I pass parameters like frameworks do in PHP?

Tags: php, url, web-frameworks

I want to pass parameters like www.example.com/user/1 where 1 is parameter which I normally would pass like www.example.com?user=1

I want to pass parameters like frameworks do. Also how will I fetch them in another page if I have multiple parameters? How would I know which parameter is which?

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: If i understand you want something like this? www.example.com?user_id=1&par=2. You can retrieve that with $_GET['param_name']. Then if you want www.example.com/id/1/par/2 you have to use .htacces file. Here is an [example](https://moz.com/blog/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls)

Comment: @Sfili_81 No I want URL like www.example.com/id/1/par/2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create friendly URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php get value of part of url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601372/php-get-value-of-part-of-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL Rewriting with .htaccess

Look at here: [URL Rewriting](https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Url Rewriting by updating your `.htaccess file`
2. You can explode the URL to get the value of your parameter in URL [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985505/get-part-of-url)
3. You can use Routing class like [AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/)

   $router = new AltoRouter();

   // map homepage
   $router->map( 'GET', '/', function() {
       require **DIR** . '/views/home.php';
   });

   // map users details page
   $router->map( 'GET|POST', '/users/[i:id]/', function( $id ) {
     $user = .....
     require **DIR** . '/views/user/details.php';
   });